# multi select component to radio buttons in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a multiselect component that needs to change to radio buttons, because only one can be selected. A string array will get submitted.

```
    <select class="form-control" *ngSwitchDefault [id]="field.name" [formControlName]="field.name" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':  isInvalid() }">
      <option *ngFor="let option of field.options | keyvalue;" [value]="option.key">{{option.value}}</option>
    </select>
```

And I need to change it to radio buttons and add an extra option called "None".
So I did this:

```
    <div *ngFor="let option of field.options | keyvalue;">
      <input type="radio" 
        [id]="field.name + '_' + option.key"
        [formControlName]="field.name" 
        [value]= "option.key" 
        [checked]="isChecked(option.key)" 
        (change)="onRadioChange($event.target.checked, option.key)"
        [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': isInvalid() }" 
      />
        
      <label [attr.for]="field.name + '_' + option.key">{{option.value}}</label>
    </div>
```

The problem I have is that when submitting I need this to behave the same way as the multi select, so it has to go through as array with a single value, rather than just the single value, and also if 'None' is selected not include it at all, like when no option was selected.
I want to avoid touching the submit function if possible as is in separate component.